# jQuery UI Sortable events - click and send to the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, events, jquery-ui-sortable

I need help with jQuery UI Sortable script.
How can i send an item to the last item on the list?

```
<ul id="drag">
    <li>
        First
        <div>x</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        Second
        <div>x</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        Third
        <div>x</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        Fourth
        <div>x</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '#drag div', function(e) {

    var item = $(this).closest('li');

    // Send `item` to the end of list...

});
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
$('#drag').sortable();

$(document).on('click', '#drag div', function (e) {
    $(this).parent().appendTo('#drag');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7PDav/

You basically take and re-append the clicked item. The append will put it at the end.